# jquery add multiple css classes to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to add another css class called popup to an .each function.

jQuery:

```
$.each(data.photos.photo, function(i, photo) {
        var imgURL = 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret + '_n.jpg';

        console.log(imgURL);

        // Pre-cache image
        $('<img />').attr({'src': imgURL, 'data-image-num': i}).load(function() {
           console.log('image loaded');
           var imageDataNum = $(this).attr('data-image-num');
           $('#photo-' + imageDataNum).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgURL + ')').removeClass('fade-out').addClass('fade-in');
        });

     });
```

CSS

```
.popup
{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
margin:100px auto;
width:200px;
height:150px;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:13px;
padding:10px;
background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
border:2px solid grey;
z-index:100000000000000000;
display:none
}
```

Thank you for your help and this is my frist post by the way so sorry if i sound nooby.

Comment: to which element do you want to add the class? the image?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
$('#photo-' + imageDataNum).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgURL + ')').removeClass('fade-out').addClass('fade-in').addClass('popup');
...
```

or

```
    $('<img />').attr({'src': imgURL, 'data-image-num': i}).load(function() {
       console.log('image loaded');
       var imageDataNum = $(this).attr('data-image-num');
       $('#photo-' + imageDataNum).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgURL + ')').removeClass('fade-out').addClass('fade-in');
    }).addClass('popup');
```

Comment: Hey and thanks for the quick response the first solution work however it failed to display the image but when checking through console in chrome the images are there and the css class has been applied

Comment: Sorry actually I just realised i'm going about this the wrong way i think. I have another function called Popup and the whole purpose is it is meant to pop up the a div in the center of the screen when an image is clicked.